# Redis with Rails 5.1 breaking Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, redis, uri

I have a Rspec test suite that has ran great until I installed Redis into my web app.

It's the two lines of code from the config/initializers/redis.rb file

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])
$redis = Redis::Namespace.new("EW", :redis => Redis.new(url: uri))
```

When I comment the above out, rspec works fine (I haven't even started to test redis yet because well, I can't).

Below is the error rspec gives me.

```
  An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/waitlist_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

URI::InvalidURIError:
  bad URI(is not URI?): 
# ./config/initializers/redis.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:655:in `block in load_config_initializer'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `load_config_initializer'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
# ./config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# ./spec/models/waitlist_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
# /Users/ptenteromano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@new_wardrobe/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---
# NoMethodError:
#   undefined method `to_str' for nil:NilClass
#   ./config/initializers/redis.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.

Randomized with seed 3749


Finished in 0.00061 seconds (files took 9.32 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 18 errors occurred outside of examples
```

I've pretty new to dealing with complex web apps and have never used Redis before so I'm a little lost on this.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: The error is very clear `bad URI(is not URI?):`  I assume the 
 env variable isn't an URI `ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was as simple as commenter mentioned. The ENV variable was not URI readable so I used an encode method and it fixed the issue.

```
encoded_url = URI.encode(ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])
uri = URI.parse(encoded_url)
```